# Slashes in Rally Query

Tags: rally

I have a Feature name such as: "This / is / the / name / of my feature ". Rally throws me an error when  I try to mention this name as a query string. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you get the error? I tested this query in [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/), a custom grid and a Ruby script using a feature named "feat/ure"

```
(Name = feat/ure)
```

and the query worked in all 3 cases.

Here is the Ruby code that query on a feature with forward slash in the name and assigns a new story to it:

```
require 'rally_api'

#Setup custom app information
headers = RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()
headers.name = "My Utility"
headers.vendor = "Nick M RallyLab"
headers.version = "1.0"

# Connection to Rally
config = {:base_url => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm"}
config[:username] = "user@co.com"
config[:password] = "secret"
config[:workspace] = "W"
config[:project] = "P"
config[:headers] = headers #from RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()

@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)

obj = {}
obj["Name"] = "new story efd3"
new_s = @rally.create("hierarchicalrequirement", obj)

query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = "portfolioitem"
query.fetch = "Name,FormattedID"

query.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/111" } 
query.project = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/222" }


query.query_string = "(Name = \"feat/ure\")"


result = @rally.find(query)
feature = result.first
puts feature

field_updates={"PortfolioItem" => feature}
new_s.update(field_updates)
```

Comment: I would like to modify my question and like to know how to deal with double quotes inside a story name, so my query string contains `"(Name = \"This story has" double quotes\")",` I get a parse error on such kind of query.

Answer (score 1):

You can also utilize the html replacements for those characters.